# Create moc files for Qt

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I'm asking for some help to write my Makefile.
I need to generate moc file for Qt, and for some reason I cannot used qmake (please don't ask why !!).

I have this code :

```
moc_%.cpp: %.h
     moc $(DEFINES) $(INCPATH) $< -o $@
```

But it doesn't work. I cannot understand why, but it needs the path ...
So I wrote something like this:

```
$1moc_$2.cpp: $1$2.h
     moc $(DEFINES) $(INCPATH) $< -o $@
```

But it doesn't work ...

So my question : How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you explain who it fails, when you use your first try?

Comment: you don't have to write your makefile. You simply have to generate it. On the other hand you should write your `.pro` file. What OS are you using?

Comment: @andrea.marangoni he can not use qmake

Comment: @BЈовић uhhh sorry..completely jumped that detail =)

Comment: Tks for quick responce ! the error is "no rule to build the target PATH/moc_FILE.cpp, needed by "all". stop" (something linke that, it's my translation ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
HEADERS=$(wildcard *.hpp)

OBJS+=$(patsubst %.hpp, %.moc.o, $(notdir $(HEADERS)))

%.moc.o : %.hpp
        moc $< | $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -xc++ -o $@ -
```

This will get all header files (all files, that have .hpp extension), create moc files and compile them right away.

Comment: I don't really understand ... I'm sorry. HEADERS get all cpp file without path, right ? OBJS ... I don't understant, and I don't see where you use it after declaration. What is OBJS_DIR ? Tks for help

Comment: @user3356365 I removed `OBJS_DIR` to make it simpler. This is going to gather all hpp files in the current directory. Then every .hpp file will be parsed using `moc` and the output will be compiled into appropriate binary file (.moc.o). Then at the end you need to link these files, along with compiled source (.cpp) files.

Comment: Sorry I was litle bite busy ... I don't understand 2 points : 1rst : OBJS is declared but not used ? - 2nd : moc file generated nust be like moc_%.cpp no ? you declared %.moc.o, is it a mistake ? tks

Comment: @user3356365 `moc $<` creates source file, and prints to standard output. `$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -xc++ -o $@ -` compiles the code from the standard output.